# Pass an object to a servlet called by a client

Tags: java, servlets, client

I have a desktop app that call a servlet through the method:

```
    public int[] identify(String path) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/my-webapp/upload");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));

        out.write("path=" + path);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String response;
        while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) {
            int[] numbers = convertOutput(response);
            s.showOutput(numbers);
            return numbers;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return null;
    }
```

I have no jsp file. It's executed by the desktop app and it works. But now when I call my servlet I need to pass to the servlet an object that I've previously instantiated. How can i do that?

Comment: Just write it to out..?

Comment: How can I write an object through a BufferedWriter?

Comment: Upon closer inspection it appears that you want to programmatically perform a file upload over HTTP, is this true? If to, then you can find an example near the bottom of the top answer of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests Let me know if that indeed solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, I upload an image, process it  on server side and then i get an output through the String response

Comment: OK, as I guessed. This was already asked and answered before.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem. Can you explain me how I can write an object through my BufferedWriter?

Comment: Get an `InputStream` of it and write it to `OutputStream`. It can really be any `InputStream` you want, such as `FileInputStream` as shown in the duplicate which exactly fits your "upload file" use case, or even `ObjectInputStream` if it's a `Serializable` Java object.